# HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode in windows 10

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

1. HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode
2. error like this

> distrib/android-emugl//host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2//GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUseProgram:2071`
>       error 0x501 draw: Could not use program error=0x501 draw: Could not
>           bind GL_ARRAY_BUFFER error=0x502

3. I did haxm installed two ram size is equal
4. ini file x and y window set to 0 it not helped

Please help me

Answer (score 2):

my environment is: Win 10/Android Studio, it does work now. no other error.

Please repair you HAX installation, and set the RAM by manually up to 1.5G
and in AVD, please set the Ram of your emulator as 1G.